# Pytorch: Backpropogate more than one loss

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I want to backpropogate more than one sample. That means more than one loss in PyTorch. I want to do that at a specific timestamp.
I am trying to do that:

```
        losso = 0
        for g, logprob in zip(G, self.action_memory):
            losso += -g * logprob
        self.buffer.append(losso)

        if (self.game_counter > self.pre_training_games):
            for element in self.buffer:
                self.policy.optimizer.zero_grad()
                element.backward(retain_graph=True)
                self.policy.optimizer.step()
```

But I got a Runtime Error:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [91, 9]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are re-using `loss`:
On the one hand, you *add* the loss of each iteration to `loss`,
while on the other hand, you `backward()` through the `loss` of each iteration.

This might be the reason for your error.

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: @DanischKhurshid replace the `losso += ...` in the first loop with `losso = ...`

Comment: but I have to add. losso is my loss fucntion

Comment: @DanischKhurshid so what is the meaning of both adding (accumulating) the loss _and_ computing the gradient for each iteration separately? what if you only `backward()` for the last loss (that basically accumulated all losses): `self.buffer[-1].backward()`?

Comment: So losso computes the loss for one timestamp (first for-loop) On a exact time point I want to compute train my model to all timespan. Thats why I wanted to backward each loss from each timestamp. This was the idea.